# "Data type mismatch in criteria expression." VS.NET 2010

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

This is part of my code, and when i run it it gave me an error in "Comando.ExecuteNonQuery()". 
Sorry, this is the text that came whit the error "Data type mismatch in criteria expression." 
i change "Direccion as char" to String, that's how is suppose to be, and i put the (') in the values section.

```
   Function Agregar_Registro(ByVal Id As String, ByVal Nombre As String, ByVal Direccion As String, ByVal Edad As String) As Boolean
    'CONVETIR 
    Dim COD As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Id)
    'CONEXION (CREA UN TIPO PUENTE DE CONNECCION ENTRE LA BBDD Y LA APLICCION)
    Dim Conexion As New OleDbConnection
    Conexion.ConnectionString = "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = F:\Proyecto Empresa\Proyecto Empresa BBDD\BBDD Maestra.accdb; Persist Security info = false"
    Dim CadenaSql As String = "Insert into Personal(id, Nombre, Direccion, Edad) "
    CadenaSql = CadenaSql + "VALUES(" & COD & " , "
    CadenaSql = CadenaSql + "                     '" & Nombre & "' , "
    CadenaSql = CadenaSql + "                     '" & Direccion & "' , "
    CadenaSql = CadenaSql + "                     '" & Edad & "' ) "
    Dim Comando As OleDbCommand = Conexion.CreateCommand()
    Comando.CommandText = CadenaSql
    Conexion.Open()
    Comando.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Conexion.Close()
    Return True
End Function
```

And mi data types in mi table are:

```
ID - Number
Nombre - Text
Direccion - Text
Edad - Number
```

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27072910/edit) your question to add the complete error message; do not simply say “it gave me an error”. Also, tell us the data types of your `Personal` table columns.

Comment: "it gave me an error" is not a problem description unless you include information on what "error" you received. We don't have the rest of your code or your database to test against, so if you don't provide that information we can't help you. What is the **specific error** you're getting, including **the exact error message**?

Comment: well, if Edad is a numeric, passing a string (using ticks and padding) will cause that error.  Use SQL Parameters, **not** ticks

Comment: @Plutonix , the thing is that this is some ''practice'' that my teacher put us to learn about conexion to databases, and well he just pass us the code and i copied just the way he had it, and it gave me so diferents errors but right know is just that one, and i don't know anythig about parameters yet.

Comment: Once again, "it gave me so differents errors" is totally meaningless unless you [edit] your question and tell us what **the specific errors** are that you see. If you call your doctor and say "I don't feel well. What's wrong and how do I feel better?", you won't get a diagnosis or treatment until you provide a lot more information, and the same is true here. If you refuse to tell us what is wrong, we can't help you find a solution to the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if you saw that I updated my answer. I had quotes around Edad, but since it's a number that didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

If Nombre and Direccion are text, then you need to quote the strings in your query. Like so:

```
Dim CadenaSql As String = "Insert into Personal(id, Nombre, Direccion, Edad) "
CadenaSql = CadenaSql + "VALUES(" & COD & " , "
CadenaSql = CadenaSql + "                     '" & Nombre & "' , "
CadenaSql = CadenaSql + "                     '" & Direccion & "' , "
CadenaSql = CadenaSql + "                     " & Edad & " ) "
```

Or you can use parameters:

```
Dim CadenaSql As String = "Insert into Personal (id, Nombre, Direccion, Edad) VALUES (@COD, @Nombre, @Direccion, @Edad)"

Dim Comando As OleDbCommand = Conexion.CreateCommand()
Comando.CommandText = CadenaSql
Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COD", COD)
Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", Nombre)
Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Direccion", Direccion)
Comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Edad", Edad)
Conexion.Open()
Comando.ExecuteNonQuery()
Conexion.Close()
```